# Use only one authentication scheme (jwt bearer)

Tags: asp.net, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authentication

I am building an ASP.Net Core API and am using JWT for authentication.

I have the following configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
          {
              cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              cfg.SaveToken = true;

              cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidateIssuer = true,
                  ValidateActor = false,
                  ValidateLifetime = false,
                  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                  ValidIssuers = Global.Issuers,
                  ValidAudiences = Global.Audiences,
                  IssuerSigningKey = Global.symmetricSecurityKey
              };

          });
    }
```

As you can see, I want to use JWT and *only* JWT.

For a few hours I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I was constantly getting a 401 on any actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I finally ended up trying `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` and it worked!

So what gives?!

How can i figure out what other authentication schemes are challenging?

Do I have to explicitly disable the default scheme (cookie)?

I would like to avoid having to specify the `AuthenticationSchemes` on all my `Authorize` tags.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm betting my hair is more pulled than your hair. It's nearly 3AM, and I've been at this since for 4 hours. Did you find a solution for this in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately the only solution I found was to use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")] everywhere...

Comment: Thought as much. Appreciate the response thanks.